# PHP current password not the same as in database

Tags: php, authentication

I create a function to edit user password here the function code.

```
function updateUser ()
{


    $current = md5($_POST['cpassword']);
    $new = md5($_POST['npassword']);
    $newc = md5($_POST['npasswordc']);

    $name = $_POST['username'];
    connectDB();

        $check = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM user WHERE user_name = '$name'") 

        or die(mysql_error());


            if ($check != $current) {

            ?> <div id="error">
                <?php die('Current password is wrong. Press back to try again.'); ?>
                </div> <?php

            }

        if ($new == $newc) :

            $sql = "UPDATE user SET password = '$new' WHERE user_name = '$name'";
            execute($sql);

            ?> <div id="error">
            <?php die('Password Successfully Updated. Back to <a href="/dashboard">dashboard</a>');
            ?> </div>  <?php

        else :  ?> <div id="error">
            <?php die('New Password did not match. Press back to try again');
            ?> </div>  <?php

        endif;


}
```

the value will be pass by the form on different page, everything seem to work fine. When I try to change password, it say successful, and when I check in the database, the md5 value is changing that mean the password was change.

But when I try to change password of same username, I still need to enter the old password for current password, even though in database it already changed?

What seem to be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a user_name twice in your db?

Comment: can you post your login code segment? the update code is ok here.

Comment: @Grrbrr404 what you mean? only one.

Comment: @Sadat i yet to create the login form, i just create a dummy form to pass the name of user to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$check` is a mysql resource, not a value. You might do

```
if($check && (mysql_num_rows($check) > 0))
{
  $res = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
  if($res['password'] != $current) {
```

Be careful of SQL injections, you should do at least

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
```

before entering it into the query.

Also, md5 is a week hashing algorithm, I strongly suggest you use a SALT, and better hash algos like at the very least sha1() or better go for the sha2 family (sha256, sha512, for ex) or bcrypt

Comment: this one work, thank you.. i thought so.. maybe will use hash() instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code... **maybe** it works. also watch the comments it explains something maybe it helps:

```
function updateUser ()
{
    $current = md5($_POST['cpassword']);
    $new = md5($_POST['npassword']);
    $newc = md5($_POST['npasswordc']);

    // first check if the passwords matches if not why waist the connection
    if ($new == $newc) {
        $name = $_POST['username'];
        connectDB();

        // why not checking your pass in the query
        // when a result is zero it means there is no match found
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM user WHERE user_name = '{$name}' AND password = '{$current}'") or die(mysql_error());
        $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);

        // You where checking a resource with a string(MD5)?
        if (mysql_num_rows($check) == 0) {
            ?><div id="error">
            <?php die('Current password is wrong. Press back to try again.'); ?>
            </div><?php
            return false;
        } else {
            // update the query with the ID you got from the check..
            // why? because a ID is always unique
            $sql = "UPDATE user SET password = '{$new}' WHERE user_id = '{$result['user_id']}'";
            execute($sql);

            ?><div id="error">
            <?php echo 'Password Successfully Updated. Back to <a href="/dashboard">dashboard</a>';
            ?></div><?php
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        ?><div id="error">
        <?php echo 'New Password did not match. Press back to try again';
        ?></div><?php 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: well this one lot better, than mine.. will try if work will use it.

Comment: @Tricker this script is still vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: @DamienPirsy i know, it stinks on every way it could ;) i also dont use the basic `mysql_query` but `mysqli`.. i just tide up his code with little fix..